# Why does this cause an "The field name is ambiguous" error?

Tags: java, interface, compiler-errors

Here is the code:

```
public class MyClass implements Inreface1, Inreface2 {
    public MyClass() {
        System.out.println("name is :: " + name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyClass();
    }
}
//Interface1
public interface Inreface1 {
    public String name="Name";
}
 //Interface2
public interface Inreface2 {
    public String name="Name";
}
```

Here is the error it causes:

> The field name is ambiguous

What is the problem?  What is ambiguous?

Comment: *"i try hard but cant find wor d ambiguous"* - [I don't believe you](http://i.imgur.com/eQBee.png).

Comment: My first though was: "I don't care about the ambiguity but how the _hell_ doesn't Java complain about _fields_ in _interfaces._" 1.8 just keeps on giving I guess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class is implementing two interfaces, and on both of them, the variable `name` is defined. Thus, when you call `name` in your class, Java is not able to determine if the variable refers to `Interface1.name` or `Interface.name`.

That's the problem in your code...

Comment: thnx for answer but what is ambiguous ?

Comment: and the way to fix it is to prefix it with the class name: `"name is "+Inreface1.name`

Comment: The variable called `name`, which is defined in your two interfaces. Change it to `foo`, and the error message will be `The field foo is ambiguous`

Answer (score 1):

Class `MyClass` implements two interfaces, which both have a `name` variable. In the constructor of `MyClass`, Java doesn't know which `name` to pick - the one from `Inreface1` or the one from `Inreface2`. You could tell it explicitly:

```
public MyClass() {
    System.out.println("name is :: " + Inreface1.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code:

```
System.out.println("name is :: " + name);
```

Which "name" should the compiler use? I's ambiguous, because could be Inreface1.name or Inreface2.name.
If you clear the ambiguity by specifying one "name" the error should disappear. For instance:

```
System.out.println("name is :: " + Inreface1.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're referring to the same variable.

I think the compiler does not know which value you are trying to pass. Have you tried changing the field variable?

Answer (score 0):

> **what is ambiguous ?**
>
> If two fields with the same name are inherited by an interface
> because, for example, two of its direct superinterfaces declare fields
> with that name, then a single ambiguous member results. Any use of
> this ambiguous member will result in a compile-time error. Thus in the
> example:

```
   interface BaseColors {
        int RED = 1, GREEN = 2, BLUE = 4;
    }
    interface RainbowColors extends BaseColors {
        int YELLOW = 3, ORANGE = 5, INDIGO = 6, VIOLET = 7;
    }
    interface PrintColors extends BaseColors {
        int YELLOW = 8, CYAN = 16, MAGENTA = 32;
    }
    interface LotsOfColors extends RainbowColors, PrintColors {
        int FUCHSIA = 17, VERMILION = 43, CHARTREUSE = RED+90;
    }
```

> the interface LotsOfColors inherits two fields named YELLOW. This is
> all right as long as the interface does not contain any reference by
> simple name to the field YELLOW. (Such a reference could occur within
> a variable initializer for a field.)
>
> Even if interface PrintColors
> were to give the value 3 to YELLOW rather than the value 8, a
> reference to field YELLOW within interface LotsOfColors would still be
> considered ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Another point is that instance variables are not allowed in interfaces. Your public string turns into a constant : public static String name; - which you get two times. More than one constant with the same name/type is definitely ambiguous.